# Excel - split and transpose with inserted rows

Tags: excel, vba, split, transpose

What code would I be using to achieve this in vba, I've been trying to adapt other codes that I have seen online to my needs but it's not working out. I'll greatly appreciate any help.

I get the data in this format:

```
Col A   Col B  Col C  Col D
QBC       T    90125  LAK-912,323.YVS-PK,US.
QOL       T    53241  LWA-324.
QEF       F    31236  PKS-634,432,243.
```

and I would like the data to be extracted as:

```
Col A   Col B  Col C  Col D
QBC       T    90125  LAK-912
QBC       T    90125  LAK-323
QBC       T    90125  YVS-PK
QBC       T    90125  YVS-US
QOL       T    53241  LWA-324
QEF       F    31236  PKS-634
QEF       F    31236  PKS-432
QEF       F    31236  PKS-243
```

Hope it is clear!

Comment: Would you accept an answer that would just take care of splitting "Col D" values, and leave the column filling to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sub create the list from the cell F2:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim RowsOffset, ColsOffset, e, k As Long
Dim Str As String
Dim StrB, StrN As String
Dim Start As Long

Range("A1").Activate
LastRow = Range(ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Address).Row

RowsOffset = 0
ColsOffset = 5
For e = 1 To LastRow
    Str = ActiveCell.Offset(e, 3).Value
    StrB = ""
    StrN = ""
    Start = 1
    For k = 1 To Len(Str)
        If Mid(Str, k, 1) = "," Then
            StrN = Mid(Str, Start, k - Start)
            Start = k + 1
            RowsOffset = RowsOffset + 1
            ActiveCell.Offset(RowsOffset, ColsOffset).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(e, 0).Value
            ActiveCell.Offset(RowsOffset, ColsOffset + 1).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(e, 1).Value
            ActiveCell.Offset(RowsOffset, ColsOffset + 2).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(e, 2).Value
            ActiveCell.Offset(RowsOffset, ColsOffset + 3).Value = StrB & StrN
        End If
        If Mid(Str, k, 1) = "." Then
            StrN = Mid(Str, Start, k - Start)
            Start = k + 1
            RowsOffset = RowsOffset + 1
            ActiveCell.Offset(RowsOffset, ColsOffset).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(e, 0).Value
            ActiveCell.Offset(RowsOffset, ColsOffset + 1).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(e, 1).Value
            ActiveCell.Offset(RowsOffset, ColsOffset + 2).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(e, 2).Value
            ActiveCell.Offset(RowsOffset, ColsOffset + 3).Value = StrB & StrN
        End If
        If Mid(Str, k, 1) = "-" Then
           StrB = Mid(Str, Start, k - Start + 1)
           Start = k + 1
        End If

    Next
```

If you want another position, change:

```
RowsOffset = 0          ' Rows Offset
ColsOffset = 5          ' Column Offset
```

If you want another sheet, the code it's a little different. YOu need to change the 8 line with Activecell with:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Offset(RowsOffset, ColsOffset).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(e, 0).Value
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly but there is just one slight edit that I was hoping that you could make. To handle a case where in a given row, the Col D is empty, so hence there is nothing to split there, and I would like to still see that row after splitting and transposing. As it stands it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

The `SplitAndExpand()` function takes a string like in the original "Col D" and returns an array of strings as wanted in the final "Col D". Modify and call Test() from the immediate window to check the function:

```
    Public Function SplitAndExpand(ByVal Str As String) As String()

            Dim sdot()    As String
            Dim scomma()  As Variant
            Dim prefix    As String
            Dim result()  As String

            Dim i  As Long
            Dim j  As Long
            Dim n  As Long

            ' This code is NOT the most efficient.

            ' 1. Split the string at ".", ignore the last empty string
            Let sdot = Strings.Split(Str, ".")
            If sdot(UBound(sdot)) = "" Then
                    ReDim Preserve sdot(0 To (UBound(sdot) - 1))
            End If

            ' 2. For each sdot substring, split it at ","
            ReDim scomma(0 To UBound(sdot))
            Let n = 0
            For i = 0 To UBound(sdot)
                    ' Split
                    Let scomma(i) = Strings.Split(sdot(i), ",")

                    ' Cumulate results from this split
                    Let n = n + UBound(scomma(i)) + 1
            Next i

            ' 3. Build result from the prefix of the first scomma string and the
            '    rest of the strings. Result array is 1-based
            ReDim result(1 To n)
            Let n = 0
            For i = 0 To UBound(scomma)
                    ' Add the first entry and calculate prefix
                    Let n = n + 1
                    Let result(n) = scomma(i)(0)
                    Let prefix = Strings.Split(result(n), "-")(0) & "-"

                    ' Assemble the rest of the entries, and save them
                    For j = 1 To UBound(scomma(i))
                            Let n = n + 1
                            Let result(n) = prefix & scomma(i)(j)
                    Next j
            Next i

            ' 4. Return value
            Let SplitAndExpand = result

    End Function


    Public Sub Test()

            Dim a() As String
            Dim k As Long


            Let a = SplitAndExpand("LAK-912,323.YVS-PK,US.")
            For k = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
                    Debug.Print a(k)
            Next k

    End Sub
```